# Convert string to MIME header

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mime

I have this string:

```
Let's begin
```

I want to use it as the subject of an email. When I receive the email, the string looks like this:

```
Let&#039;s begin
```

After some research, I learned that email headers can only contain ASCII characters, but there are ways to encode symbols. I've tried using `mb_encode_mimeheader()` but I can't get it to work, and it seems like. Is there another way in PHP to simply translate a string to an acceptable MIME header? Here's my code, I'm using Wordpress 3.8.1 (latest) and PHP 5.3.

```
$sub = "Let's begin";
$email_sendto = $author_email;
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$email_subject = mb_encode_mimeheader ( $sub, 'UTF-8' );
$email_headers[] = 'From: '.$sender_name.' <'.$sender_email.'>';
$email_headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$email_headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL;
ob_start();
include(base_url_server . '/includes/email/userinquiry.php');
$email_content = ob_get_clean();

wp_mail( $email_sendto, $email_subject, $email_content, $email_headers );
```

Comment: How are you checking the received email? From some webmail system where that webmail would need to escape the apostrophe?

Note that an apostrophe is perfectly valid ASCII so your suggested explanation doesn't really make sense.

You don't need the PHP_EOLs in your email headers, I doubt that would make a difference though.

Comment: If apostrophes are valid ASCII then my issue must be somewhere else. And I'm checking the emails in the latest version of Outlook, using a test email address. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a Wordpress issue.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/apostrophes-show-up-incorrectly-in-email-subjects